# Можно ли при создании Entity персистнуть будущий ID?

Tags: php, symfony2, symfony3

```
$agent = new OrganizationAgent();
$closure = (new AgentViewClosure())
                ->setAncestor($agent)
                ->setDescendant($agent)
                ->setPath($agent->getId())
                ->setLevel(self::DEFAULT_LEVEL);
$agent->addDescendantClosure($closure)
                ->addAncestorClosure($closure);

$em->persist($closure);
```

$agent->getId() - тут будет null.  Как можно туда передать id?

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить метод

```
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}
```

После этого:

```
$entity = new Product();
$entity->setId(1);
// ...

// вот это важно
$em->getClassMetaData(get_class($entity))->setIdGenerator(new \Doctrine\ORM\Id\AssignedGenerator());

$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
```

Взято с http://www.ens.ro/2012/07/03/symfony2-doctrine-force-entity-id-on-persist/

Comment: Я добавил subscriber на postPersist  там есть id но entity closure приходится флашить - единственный минус

Answer (score 1):

То что вам нужно - это "каскадное" сохранение, т.к. вы создали две сущности и первая зависит от второй.

Пример кода:

```
<?php
    class AgentViewClosure
    {
        //...
        /**
         * Bidirectional - One-To-Many
         *
         * @OneToMany(targetEntity="OrganizationAgent", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
         */
        private $author;
        //...
    }
```

Особое внимание обратите на `cascade={"persist", "remove"}`. Подробнее можно прочитать [тут](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations)